# Frequently Updating Stored Data for a Numerical Experiment using Python

Tags: python, pickle, numerical-methods

I am running a numerical experiment that requires many iterations.  After each iteration, I would like to store the data in a pickle file or pickle-like file in case the program times-out or a data structure becomes tapped.  What is the best way to proceed.  Here is the skeleton code:

```
data_dict = {}                       # maybe a dictionary is not the best choice
for j in parameters:                 # j = (alpha, beta, gamma) and cycle through
    for k in number_of_experiments:  # lots of experiments (10^4)
        file = open('storage.pkl', 'ab')
        data = experiment()          # experiment returns some numerical value
                                     # experiment takes ~ 1 seconds, but increase
                                     # as parameters scale
        data_dict.setdefault(j, []).append(data)
        pickle.dump(data_dict, file)
        file.close()
```

Questions:

1. Is shelve a better choice here?  Or some other python library that I am not aware?
2. I am using data dict because it's easier to code and more flexible if I need to change things as I do more experiments.  Would it be a huge advantage to use a pre-allocated array?
3. Does opening and closing files affect run time?  I do this so that I can check on the progress in addition to the text logs I have set up.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: For your "open" overhead I'm getting about 39 microseconds for open with 'ab' options for a few bytes file, 41 microseconds (us) for 1kB, 44  microseconds for ~10kB, 158 us for 100kB and 2MB and 162 us for 20MB files.  So not a lot if your file size is below 20MB... This is with an SSD so YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming you are using `numpy` for your numerical experiments, instead of [pickle](http://www.benfrederickson.com/2014/02/12/dont-pickle-your-data.html) I would suggest using [numpy.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).
2. Keep it simple and make optimizations only if it you feel that the script runs too long.
3. Opening and closing files does affect the run time, but having a backup is anyway better.

And I would use `collections.defaultdict(list)` instead of plain `dict` and `setdefault`.

Answer (score 1):

Shelve is probably not a good choice, however...

You might try using `klepto` or `joblib`.  Both are good at caching results, and can use efficient storage formats.

Both `joblib` and `klepto` can save your results to a file on disk, or to a directory.  Both can also leverage the `numpy` internal storage format and/or compression on save… and also save to memory mapped files, if you like.

If you use `klepto`, it takes the dictionary key as the filename, and saves the value as the contents.  With `klepto`, you can also pick whether you want to use `pickle` or `json` or some other storage format.

```
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun  2 2014, 01:33:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import klepto
>>> data_dict = klepto.archives.dir_archive('storage', cached=False, serialized=True)     
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> for j in string.ascii_letters:
...   for k in range(1000):
...     data_dict.setdefault(j, []).append([int(10*random.random()) for i in range(3)])
... 
>>>
```

This will create a directory called `storage` that contains pickled files, one for each key of your `data_dict`.  There are keywords for using `memmap` files, and also for compression level.  If you choose `cached=False`, then instead of dumping to file each time you wrote to `data_dict`, you'd write to memory each time… and you could then use `data_dict.dump()` to dump to disk whenever you choose… or you could pick a memory limit that when you hit it, you'd dump to disk.  Additionally, you can also pick a caching strategy (like `lru` or `lfu`) for deciding which keys you would purge from memory and dump to disk.

Get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

or get `joblib` here: https://github.com/joblib/joblib

If you refactor, you could probably come up with a way to do this so it could take advantage of a pre-allocated array.  However, it might depend on the profile of how your code runs.

Does opening and closing files affect run time? Yes.  If you use `klepto`, you can set the granularity of when you want to dump to disk.  Then you can pick a trade-off of speed versus intermediate storage of results.

Comment: Thank you for this mini-tutorial!  Really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. I probably remember enough of joblib to add an example of that as well, if you find that the above doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hey Mike, Know this question was officially closed, but have recently run into this [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924397/python-multiprocessing-and-serializing-data) and am pretty stuck.  I have emailed it to my knowledgeable friends in hopes someone will answer it, but no luck yet.  I am wondering if you have encountered this difficulty with such data and how you solved it.  In fact, I am commenting here, in the hope that one of these modules might actually remedy the situation.

Comment: I ended up optimizing the actual python code so didn't need to implement data storage using the modules you suggested to speed up run time; hence the reason, I stuck with pickle just to get it working the first time!